# Sphinx "reverse" search

Tags: search, sphinx

We have a website where users put up ads for stuff they want to sell, with parameters such as price, location, title and description. These can then be searched for using sphinx and allowing users to specify min- and maxprice, a location with a searchradius (using google maps) etc. Users can choose to save these searches and get emails when new ads appear that fit their search. Herein lies the problem: We want to perform a reverse search every time an ad is posted. With the price, location, title and description as parameters we want to search through all the saved "searches" and get the ones that would have found the ad. The min- and maxprice should just be performed in a query i suppose, and some Quorom syntax to get all ads with at least 2 or mby just 1 occurance in the title/description. Our problem lies mostly in the geo-search. How do we find all searches where the "search-circles" would include our newly posted location without performing a search for every saved search?

That is the main-question, any comment on our suggested solution to the other problems is also very welcome. Thank you in advance / Jenny

Comment: Just as a 'comment' - the emerging term for this type of search is Prospective Search. That migth help you find relevent backgound info

Answer (score 0):

The standard 'geo-search' support on sphinx should work just as well on a Prospective Index, as a normal retrospective search.

Having built a sphinx 'index' of all the saved searches...

And you run a query using the 'ad' as the search query:- rather than the 'filter' using a fixed radius, you just use the radius from the attribute (ie the radius stored on the particular query) - if using the API cant use setFilterRange directly, need to use setSelect, to make a new virtual attribute.

```
$cl->setSelect("*,IF(@geodist<radius,1,0) as myfilter");
$cl->setFilter('myfilter',array(1));
```

(and yes, the min/maxprice can just be done with normal filters too - just inverting the logic to that you would use in a retrospective search)

... the complication is in the 'full-text' query, if the saved search is anything more than a single keyword, but you appear to have already figured out that part.